# Cutting down on Exchange 2013 .log Files in Mailbox Database folders

Tags: log-files, exchange-2013

The logs found in: C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\Mailbox\Mailbox Database

Are these used to support the indexing or something important? I only ask because they take up a chunk of space and if they're just used for error/warning logging I was wondering if it was possible cut down on them through a setting I'm unaware of?

Comment: Its frightening when someone is given control of an Exchange server, and the first thing they think when they see the transaction logs is, "better clean these up".

Comment: It gets slightly better when you look back at your original question and see it's the source of a duplicate from someone else being an idiot. And also to admire how far you've come, and to serve as an example for the future. I hope to hell it's a badly cropped screenshot in some Exchange admin educator's slideshow of "this is why we have job security" slides.

Comment: @maik We've all got to start somewhere and sometimes we're put in situations where we have to learn. The fact that we both had the sense to come and ask the question before doing something does count for something!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are the Exchange transaction logs. They are necessary for the proper operation of the mailbox database. The way to "cut them down" is to perform a Full backup of the Information Store with an Exchange aware backup program (like Windows Server Backup) that can flush the transaction logs, which will delete the transaction logs that have been committed to the mailbox database.

An alternate way of "cutting them down" would be to enable circular logging on the mailbox database, as long as you understand the implications of doing so.

Comment: Thanks @joeqwerty , got us onto a proper backup schedule now, can't believe it wasn't before. One database though has had half it's transaction logs moved by someone (presumably to save space?). Is it safe to move them back and then before the backup to truncate them? That DB has never been backed up either.